# Elasticsearch NEST - System.StackOverflowException when running Index

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

When I run this code:

```
var result = _client.Index<EntityType>(item, i => i.Index(n));
```

I'm getting this error:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.StackOverflowException An unhandled
> exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in
> Elasticsearch.Net.dll

The full method:

```
public bool Index<EntityType>(EntityType item, int attempt = 0) where EntityType : class, IDomainEntity<int>
{
    const int maxRetries = 5;
    if (item == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    var type = item.GetType();
    var attributes = type.CustomAttributes;
    string n = "";

    foreach (var attribute in attributes)
    {
        foreach (var arg in attribute.NamedArguments)
        {
            if (arg.MemberName == "RelationName")
            {
                n = arg.TypedValue.Value.ToString().ToLower();
            }
        }
    }

    var result = _client.Index<EntityType>(item, i => i.Index(n));
    if (!CheckResponse(result) && attempt < maxRetries)
    {
        RefreshClient<EntityType>();
        attempt++;
        return Index(item, attempt);
    }
    RefreshClient<EntityType>();
    return result.IsValid;
}
```

Comment: What is `IdType` of property `Id`?

Comment: @RussCam int. I use a generic for allowing string id's too.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that (late late night :)) Do you have a complete reproducible example that can be shared (here or as a gist)?

Comment: @RussCam I actually think it might be the same as your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51851703/3935156), I had linked that in my question before realising you had answered it.

Comment: That's my suspicion too

Comment: @RussCam Do you see any way to apply that answer to my code? I have added the full method into the question now. It’s a generic method as it can index any type.

Comment: Do you have a constructed instance of a type with which to run the method that you can share? e.g. `var item = new GroceryItem( /* fully hydrated model */);`

Comment: @RussCam I have just added it to the bottom of the question. Take note of the blurb of text above it, explaining it must be an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `[PropertyName("propertyToIgnoreInElasticsearch", Ignore = true)]` from NEST to my POCO fields which were causing an infinite loop while Indexing. It ignores a field from the Elasticsearch Index so it is not indexed.

for example:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class VeganItem<VeganItemEstablishmentType>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("veganItemEstablishments", Ignore = true)]
    public virtual ICollection<VeganItemEstablishmentType> VeganItemEstablishments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to see you got it sorted. In general, it's better to create specific POCOs for interacting with Elasticsearch. Complex objects such as those used with ORMs like Entity Framework and NHibernate that can include lazily loaded entities and self-referencing loops can cause problems when serializing to JSON, to send to Elasticsearch