# ES NEST - How to Create an index and Bulk index dynamic objects with geometry (geo_point or geo_shape)?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, geometry, nest, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I have a Dataset for which I don't know or have the type in advance, nor the number of properties or their type.

On execution, I obtain for that Dataset a DatasetSchema that contain the names, types and some flags for the properties.

For geometry properties I have their GeoJson representation stored as string and I have some flags (isGeoShape, isGeoPoint) that tell the ES property type.

I'm also using [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) if it's needed to parse those GeoJsons to actual Geometry objects, but i rather not do this extra parsing and use the GeoJson strings instead.

```
class DatasetSchema {
    List<DatasetField> Fields;
}

class DatasetField { 
    string Name;
    Type DataType;
    bool isGeoShape;
    bool isGeoPoint;
}
```

Questions:

1. How can I create such an ES index with unknown / dynamic mappings schema with NEST high level client with those geometry properties?
2. How can I Bulk index those documents with NEST high level client with Bulk or [BulkAll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/indexing-documents.html#_advanced_bulk_indexing) APIs with those geometry properties?

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823724/index-dynamic-objects-with-elasticsearch-nest-stackoverflow-exception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744742/index-a-dynamic-object-using-nest)  that the bulk indexing might be done with BulkDescriptor:

```
dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    // ….
var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();
foreach (var doc in values)
{
    descriptor.Index<object>(i => i
        .Index("abc")
        .Id((Id)doc.Id)
        .Document((object)doc));
}
client.Bulk(descriptor);
```

Still, I’m curious how geometry types should be treated?

Thank you very much!
Any thoughts or suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) will be a good fit for your use case, this feature gives you a great way to control how elasticsearch maps your dynamic data schema.

You can leverage [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#match-unmatch) parameter and control field type based on field name. If the instance of `DatasetField` has `IsGeoPoint` set to `true` we can prefix elasticsearch field name with GeoPoint and configure dynamic template to create `goe_point` field for names prefixed with GeoPoint

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic_templates": [{
                "geo_shape": {
                    "match": "GeoShape*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "geo_shape"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "geo_point": {
                    "match": "GeoPoint*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is a sample C# app showing it in action

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string indexName = "my_index";
        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
        var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        await elasticClient.Indices.DeleteAsync(indexName);
        //create index mapping with two dynamic templates,
        //based on field suffix elasticsearch will map field to specific type
        var indexResponse = await elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync(indexName, d => d
            .Map(map => map
                .DynamicTemplates(dt => dt
                    .DynamicTemplate("geo_shape", gs => gs.Match("GeoShape*").Mapping(m => m.GeoShape(s => s)))
                    .DynamicTemplate("geo_point", gs => gs.Match("GeoPoint*").Mapping(m => m.GeoPoint(p => p)))
                )));

        //some same data matching your schema
        var data = new List<DatasetField>
        {
            new () { Name = "Field1", IsGeoPoint = true },
            new () { Name = "Field2", IsGeoShape = true },
        };

        var document = new EsDocument();
        foreach (var datasetField in data)
        {
            //if the field is of type geo shape, prefix field name with GeoShape,
            //geo_shape dynamic template will match field name and will create geo_point type for it
            if (datasetField.IsGeoShape)
            {
                document.Add($"GeoShape{datasetField.Name}", new PointGeoShape(new GeoCoordinate(0, 0)));
            }
            //if the field is of type geo point, prefix field name with GeoPoint,
            //geo_point dynamic template will match field name and will create geo_shape type for it
            if (datasetField.IsGeoPoint)
            {
                document.Add($"GeoPoint{datasetField.Name}", new GeoLocation(0, 0));
            }
        }

        var response = await elasticClient.IndexDocumentAsync(document);
    }

    //this class is just an alias to dictionary
    class EsDocument : Dictionary<string,object>{}

    class DatasetField
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsGeoShape { get; set; }
        public bool IsGeoPoint { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This will produce following elasticsearch mapping

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic_templates": [{
                    "geo_shape": {
                        "match": "GeoShape*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "geo_shape"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "geo_point": {
                        "match": "GeoPoint*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "GeoPointField1": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                },
                "GeoShapeField2": {
                    "type": "geo_shape"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When it comes to bulk indexing documents, the easiest way is to use `IndexManyAsync` extension method

```
await elasticClient.IndexManyAsync(new List<EsDocument>());
```

Please also have a look at [this blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/indexing-documents-with-the-nest-elasticsearch-net-client) describing indexing multiple documents in detail. Check "Multiple documents" section.

UPDATE: add new dynamic template to a mapping with existing dynamic templates

```
var map = (await elasticClient.Indices.GetMappingAsync<EsDocument>()).Indices["your_index_name"];
var dynamicTemplates = map.Mappings.DynamicTemplates;
//add new
dynamicTemplates.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, IDynamicTemplate>());
await elasticClient.Indices.PutMappingAsync(new PutMappingRequest("your_index_name") { DynamicTemplates = dynamicTemplates });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rob! Still, do you know how to conditionally / programmatically add / define ```dynamicTemplate``` based on some conventions from my input data schema?

Comment: Yes, you can use `PutMapping` method like `await elasticClient.Indices.PutMapping<EsDocument>(m => m.DynamicTemplates());` to update and add new dynamic templates into your existing mapping based on your conditions.

Comment: Great, sounds like what i need! Still, is there a way to call ```PutMapping``` for specific Index by name? I see ```PutMappingAsync(IPutMappingRequest request, CancellationToken ct = default);``` and ```PutMappingAsync<TDocument>(Func<PutMappingDescriptor<TDocument>, IPutMappingRequest> selector, CancellationToken ct = default);```

Comment: Sure, you can specify index with `Index()` part of the descriptor like `await elasticClient.Indices.PutMapping<EsDocument>(m => m.Index(your_index_name_goes_here).DynamicTemplates())`.

Comment: For eg.: I create an index with 2 dynamic templates. After calling ```PutMappingAsync``` with one dynamic template, the initial 2 templates are replaced with the latter one. The outcome is to have all the 3 dynamic templates in the end. Any thoughts?

Comment: See your point, check my update. Think the only way is to retrieve mapping for an index, add a new dynamic template, and send back old + new.