# "System.StackOverflowException" error when try to get a dynamic proppery from an ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, stack-overflow

I met a weird error in my job, it happened when I tried to access a dynamic property in a special method of a special class. After researching, I found the code that made that problem but I still don't know why.

Here is my code ( I use .NET 4.5 )

```
public class MyCommand<TResult>
    : Command<MyCommand<TResult>>
   where TResult : class
{
}

public class MyDacAction : DacActionBase<MyDacAction, MyCommand<string>>
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
        dynamic x = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        x.AAA = 100;
        int b = x.AAA;
    }
}

public abstract class DacActionBase<TCommand, TDacCommand>
    where TCommand : class
    where TDacCommand : class, new()
{
    public virtual void Execute()
    {

    }
}

public abstract class Command<TCommand>
   : CommandBase<TCommand>
    where TCommand : class
{
    public virtual void Execute()
    {
    }
}

public abstract class CommandBase<TCommand> where TCommand : class
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new MyDacAction();
        test.Execute();
    }
}
```

If you create a console app and run this code, you will see the StackOverflowException at this line

```
int b = x.AAA;
```

When testing, I found two changes that the error will not be threw

1.

```
public class MyCommand
    : Command<MyCommand>
{
}

public class MyDacAction : DacActionBase<MyDacAction, MyCommand>
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
        dynamic x = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
        x.AAA = 100;
        int b = x.AAA;
    }
}
```

2.

```
public abstract class Command<TCommand>
    where TCommand : class
{
    public virtual void Execute()
    {
    }
}
```

Can you tell me why this error happened ?

Comment: A stack overflow exception mainly occurs because something has filled the stack to the brim, the actual code location that overflows the stack may or may not be relevant to the problem. Can you ensure that the stack is not already full when you get to that method?

Comment: Looks like a Microsoft bug! If you comment out the line `int b = x.AAA;` it works fine! I would report this on Microsoft.Connect.

Comment: Who voted to close this as unclear? The OP has provided compilable code that demonstrates the problem!

Comment: Looks similar to this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612325/stackoverflowexception-when-accessing-member-of-nested-class-via-a-dynamic-refer) and this [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672775/stackoverflowexception-when-accessing-member-of-generic-type-via-dynamic-net-c) one ... and I'd say that the ExpandoObject is not needed, just dynamic x = 0 should be enough...

Comment: @MachineLearning You are correct: I just tried it with `dynamic x = 0; int y = x;` and it fails (note, however, that you need the `y = x;`). It looks like that's the answer. It's a Microsoft bug.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Sure. I tried to edit my comment again (to add it clearly) after 5 minutes (and I didn't want to comment again :-) ) But - instead of `int y = x;` you you can do `Print(x);` with `static void Print(object obj) { }` to be on the **same** page of the **nice** SSCCE posted in the first answer of my second link above

Comment: Note that the bug was reported to Microsoft in 2014, but it hasn't been fixed yet (and the link to the bug is dead!)

Comment: @MatthewWatson It is this open [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7527)

Answer (score 3):

There is an **open** issue [#7527](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7527) in the **CoreFX** repository

> Dynamic type resolution goes into infinite recursion

with the following [repro.txt](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/files/205290/repro.txt) for this bug.

```
namespace SOE2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // vvv--- changing "dynamic" to "var" or "string" here fixes the issue
            dynamic parsedDocument = "";

            var mystery = new FailingClass<string>();

            Console.WriteLine("Entering...");
            mystery.FailingMethod(parsedDocument);
            Console.WriteLine("... and we are back!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public abstract class CommonBase<T>
    {
    }

    // Technically, this class does nothing and deriving from it should be identical to deriving from CommonBase
    public abstract class FailingClassBase<T> : CommonBase<T>
    {
    }

    // However, deriving from CommonBase instead of FailingClassBase here also fixes the issue
    // ----------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    public class FailingClass<T> : FailingClassBase<FailingClass<T>>
    {
        public void FailingMethod(T src)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to say, this is now a closed issue. Expect a fix with the next version of .NET Core.